# How to turn the drillthrough filter off in a single visual in Power BI?

Tags: filter, powerbi, drillthrough

I'm working with Power BI Desktop. I have a report page with a visual component that applies the drillthrough action. When I use the drillthrough, I get into the next report page.

In the next report page, I have several visualizations. But there is a single visual component in which I don't want to use the filters that are automatically activated when using the drillthrough. The problem is that I can't turn off the filters from only that single component.

Is this problem impossible to solve, or is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't turn off drill-through on a visual by visual basis. The only options you have are [Cross-report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-cross-report-drill-through) and [Keep all filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-cross-report-drill-through). Keep all filters allows you to specify what filters are kept, depending on you requirements this may suit your need

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can create Measures that use DAX that ignore filters in order to override filters or selection context, and use those measures in your one visual in place of the usual columns.

For example, instead of Sales, create a measure UnfilteredSales, and have DAX like:

Unfiltered sales = ALL(Sales[Sales])

Or if there were some filters you wanted to apply, but not all:

total year sales = CALCULATE(SUM(Sales[Sales]),FILTER(ALLEXCEPT(Sales,Sales[Country]),Sales[Relative Year]=0))